# What is the probability of getting a 3 or higher on a six sided die, if I reroll after failing the first time?

Tags: probability

Just as the question says... What is the probability of rolling a 3 or higher on a six sided die, if I reroll the die a second time when I fail the first time?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 I think the probability is 8/9. You're calculating the probability that you get three or higher given you failed the first roll.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by considering two cases. Let $A$ be "roll three or higher". Then $$P(A)=P(A\mid E)P(E)+P(A\mid E^c)P(E^c)$$ where $E$ is "failed the first time".

This gives $P(A)= 2/3\cdot 1/3+1\cdot 2/3=8/9$. Another way of seeing this is to calculate the probability of consecutively rolling less than three. This is just $1/3\cdot 1/3=1/9$ so $P(A)=1-1/9=8/9$.

Comment: aren't $A$ and $E^c$ mutually exclusive?

Comment: $P(A\mid E^c)=1$, actually. If you didn't fail the first time, then you did roll three or higher. I did have an extra wording for the event $A$, my bad. =)

Comment: I see, I misinterpreted the problem. The question could be rephrased as "what is the probability of getting $3$ or higher in at most two tosses of the dice?" Right?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 Yes, correct.

Answer (score 3):

Let us pretend that we roll the dice twice and consider the following elementary events $$\{(1f, 2f),(1f, 2s),(1s, 2f),(1s, 2s)\}.$$

(Here the numbers refer to the first and the second trial, and $f$ and $s$ refer to failure and success.) The probabilities of these elementary events are $$\frac 19,\frac29,\frac29,\frac49.$$

We are interested in the following  probability

$$P(\{(1f, 2s),(1s, 2f),(1s, 2s)\})=\frac29+\frac29+\frac49=\frac89.$$

Answer (score 2):

The first time you roll, you have probability $\frac{2}{3}$ to succeed. In the case you fail (which happens with probability $\frac{1}{3}$), you roll again, with the same probability of success. So we add $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}$. This gives $\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{8}{9}$.

Answer (score 0):

I respectively disagree with the previous answers as each roll of the die is completely independent of the other die. The events are not connected. When I took statistics this was one of the most important concepts that was stressed.
Ie. Flip a coin and if you get 3 heads in a row the next flip you still have a 50/50 chance for heads or tails
So rolling a 3 or higher would mean a 3,4,5 or 6. That is 4 out of 6 for a 2/3 probability or 66%.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you fail the first time, this weighs in the probability "toll". That is why the calulation accounts for "fail and then win" which gives $1/3\cdot 2/3$ and the disjoint event "win at the first toss" which gives $2/3$ for a total of $8/9$. Alternatively, you can note that you're calculating the probability of getting three or higher in at most two tosses, and the probability of *not* getting three or higher in at most two tosses is $1/9$, which is the probability of getting one or two in both the first and second toss.

Comment: (Do you mean "respectfully disagree"?) Note you have simply calculated the probability of obtaining three or higher in a *single* toss.

Comment: The rolls are independent, yes. What is *not* independent is whether or not there is a second roll at all.

Comment: Hi. I agree with those statements. I guess it's how the question is interpreted. The probability of the second die by itself is how I stated it but if the intent is the sample space to be two rolls then you are correct. Maybe the question could be reworked as it implied to me that they wanted the probability of the second roll.